# How to clone second onto primary partition in MacOS

Tags: macos, partitioning, partition-copy

I have weird situation in my iMac drive. I have 2 equal size partitions (2x250Gb). I have tested new OS version (Sierra) on second partition and erased primary partition cause Sierra works smoothly. I wanted to reduce size of primary partition to use more space for secondary, but that cannot be done as I read. Is there any way, without additional HDD to copy second partition to first one, and then to be able to remove second partition so system will be on whole drive. I have tried to restore first partition using disk tools with second partition as a source, but, since it is bootable partition, disk utility won't copy it with message "Source volume is read-write and cannot be unmounted, so it can't be block copied.".

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) could clone one partition to the other, allowing you to then delete the 2nd partition & extend the first. You've probably already discovered you cannot 'extend' to earlier on the drive, only later. As far as I'm aware, CCC actually just uses a built-in command-set, `dd` but is a lot easier to work with than Terminal.

Comment: @Tetsujin was right. CCC done the job. I just clone second partition to primary, make primary partition to boot with, rebooted and removed second partition (merged with primary)! Thanks man!

Comment: Glad it worked - I normally don't like to post "software recommendations" as answers, but honestly I think CCC is a no-brainer for this type of issue... let me throw it in as a quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) could clone one partition to the other, allowing you to then delete the 2nd partition & extend the first.

You've probably already discovered you cannot 'extend' to earlier on the drive, only later.

As far as I'm aware, CCC actually just uses a built-in command-set, `dd` but is a lot easier to work with than Terminal.